# Turn selector name into an iterable string or object

Tags: angular, typescript

My code is working but, I don't want it to be copy paste like what I provided, is there anyway to turn this into an iterable item? I commented on the part that needs to be iterated.

Here is mycode:

```
  <li ngbNavItem="training-types">
    <a ngbNavLink>Training Types</a>
    <ng-template ngbNavContent>
      <app-training-types></app-training-types> // turn this into a string or something that can be iterated
    </ng-template>
  </li>
  <li ngbNavItem="training-resources">
    <a ngbNavLink>Training Resources</a>
    <ng-template ngbNavContent>
      <app-training-resources></app-training-resources>  // turn this into a string or something that can be iterated
    </ng-template>
  </li>
```

Comment: You have only two items or they could extend as well?

Comment: Never tried it in such a place, but how about using interpolation? `<{{item}}></{{item}}>` + `*ngFor` and a string list (in the component).

Comment: @KamranKhatti it can extend

Comment: @GunnarB.Thanks will try

Comment: @GunnarB.it doesn't work

Comment: Ok, that doesn't even compile because of the `/`. Doesn't seem to be possible to interpolate that. You can use the interpolation/binding like in Eliseos answer and wrap the component in a ngSwitch.

Answer (score 0):

**WRONG ANSWER**

just create an array of object and iterate over the `<li>`. For this use ng-container (I don't be prety sure you can use the `*ngFor` in the own "li")

```
items=[
       {type:"training-types",header:"Training Types"},
       {type:"training-resources",header:"Training Resources"}
      ]

  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
    <li [ngbNavItem]="item.type">
      <a ngbNavLink>{{item.header}}</a>
      <ng-template ngbNavContent>
        <app-training-types></app-training-types> 
      </ng-template>
    </li>
  </ng-container>
```

Comment: This needs to add the relevant point: Interpolating the name of the component in the ng-template -> `app-training-types`, `app-training-resources`, ...

Comment: Yeah that's the main goal but I want the "<app-training-types></app-training-types>" into an iteratable.

Comment: sorry, forget my answer, I read bad, I'm afraid that, using only .html you need make a switch case